# How to delete specific elements from an array while not deleting its later occurences

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list

Take integer input from a user and then delete the elements from an array having those many consecutive ocurences from the array.

Eg the input array is "aabcca" and the input from the user is 2.
Then the answer should be "ba".

I tried it when the elements are not repeated. My code works perfectly for examples like "aaabbccc".

```
for j in range(t, (n+1)):
    if (t == n):
        if (count == k):
            array = [x for x in array if x != temp]
        print array
        exit()
    if (t == n and count == k):
        array = [x for x in array if x != temp]
        print array
        exit()
    if temp == data[j]: 
        count += 1
        t += 1
    if temp != data[j]:
        if count == k:
            array = [x for x in array if x != temp]
        temp = data[t]
        count = 1
        t += 1
```

Comment: can you explain why `input array is "aabcca" and the input from the user is 2. Then the answer should be "ba".`?

Comment: @recnac that is the problem statement. For example if you have a string aaabca and the user input is 3 then the output should be bca. Only the consecutive characters with the length mentioned by the user should be deleted.Another example would be if the array is abbcb and the input is 2 then the output would be acb.

Comment: thanks, I must got lost in somewhere @Atharva Biwalkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `sliding window` or `two pointers` to solve it.

the key point is use `[start, end]` range to record a consecutive seq, and only add the seq whose length less than `n`:

```
def delete_consecutive(s, n):
    start, end, count = 0, 0, 0
    res, cur = '', ''
    for end, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == cur:
            count += 1
        else:
            # only add consecutive seq less than n
            if count < n:
                res += s[start:end]
            count = 1
            start = end
            cur = c

    # deal with tail part
    if count < n:
        res += s[start:end+1]

    return res
```

test and output:

```
print(delete_consecutive('aabcca', 2))      # output: ba
print(delete_consecutive('aaabbccc', 3))    # output: bb
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: Thank you so much @recnac. I see that the key was using a function which I was not doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that:

```
def remove_consecutive(s, n):
    # Number of repeated consecutive characters
    count = 0
    # Previous character
    prev = None
    # Pieces of string of result
    out = []
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        # If new character
        if c != prev:
            # Add piece of string without repetition blocks
            out.append(s[i - (count % n):i])
            # Reset count
            count = 0
        # Increase count
        count += 1
        prev = c
    # Add last piece
    out.append(s[len(s) - (count % n):])
    return ''.join(out)

print(remove_consecutive('aabcca', 2))
# ba
print(remove_consecutive('aaabbccc', 2))
# ac
print(remove_consecutive('aaabbccc', 3))
# bb
```